# не работает функция через указатели в C++

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Одна функция работает нормально, а вторая нет. Суть задачи - найти произведение элементов массива с помощью функции, которая будет возвращать результат по указателям.

Код всей программы:

```
using namespace std; 

int* FindMax(int *arr, int *n)
{
    int* max = arr;
    for (int i=0; i<(*n); i++) 
    {   
        if ((*max)<(*(arr + i))) {
            
        (*max) = (*(arr + i));   }
        
        
    } 
    return max;
} 

int* FindProiz(int *arr, int *n)
{   
    int t = 1; 
    int* P = &t;
    for (int i=1; i<(*n); i++) 
    {   
        (*P)= (*P) * (*(arr + i)); 
    } 
    return P;
}


int main()
{   
    int n = 0; 
    cin>>n;
    
    
    int *arr = new int [n]; 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        cout<<"arr["<<i<<"] = "; 
        cin>>(*(arr + i)); 
        cout<<endl; 
    }
    
    cout<<"Max = "<< *(FindMax(arr, &n))<<endl; 
    cout<<"Proiz = "<< *(FindProiz(arr, &n))<<endl; 
}
```

Comment: А куда вы пишете? И что? Вот тут: `std::cin >>(*(arr + i))` — это же просто запись по нулевому адресу... Да и чтение в указатель на `int` - это что-то странное. А для начала - у вас в первой же функции не хватает фигурной скобки (или лишняя :) ). Вы вообще этот код компилировали или нет?

Comment: Задача по учёбе, тот момент на кот орый вы указали -просто проверка на тип данных, код я компилировал, но возможно, что-то удалилось пока редактировал для sof, можете уточнить, чтение указателя это про аргументы ф-ии? если да, то просто не смог сделать по другому

Comment: Какая "проверка на тип данных"?... 8-/

Comment: Что вводимый элемент типа int, иначе выводит спец.сообщение - опять таки требование по учёбе

Comment: Так Ваш код даже не компилируется:) - Фигурной скобки не хватает -  if ((*max)<(*(arr + i))) {
        (*max) = (*(arr + i)); Так что не работает - то?

Comment: Вроде исправил, у меня он нормально ком-ля, не знаю в чем была проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вобщем, так. Работа с указателями не означает, что надо делать через указатели всё. Если это учебное задание - то от вас явно ждут просто умения работать с массивом через указатель. Так что я бы исправил ваш код так:

```
int* FindMax(int *arr, int n) //функция для нах-ия максимума
{
    int* max = arr;
    for (int i = 1; i< n; i++)
        if (*max < *(arr + i)) max = arr + i;
    return max;
}

int FindProiz(int *arr, int n) //функция для нах-ия произведения
{   
    int P = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        P *= *(arr + i);
    return P;
}

int main()
{   
    int n = 0;                              //вводим кол-во эл-ов,потом их сравним
    cout<<"Размерность массива n = ";
    while (!(std::cin >>n && n>0))
    {
        cin.clear();
        while(cin.get()!='\n');
        cout<<"ВВЕДЕНО НЕВЕРНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ"<<endl;
        cin.clear();
    }
    cout << endl;
    int * arr = new int[n];                   //иниз-ем массив указателей
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"arr["<<i<<"] = ";
        while (!(std::cin >> *(arr + i)))
        {
            cin.clear();
            while(cin.get()!='\n');
            cout<<"ВВЕДЕНО НЕВЕРНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ"<<endl;
            cin.clear();
        }
    }

    cout<<"Max = "  << *FindMax(arr, n)  << endl;
    cout<<"Proiz = "<< FindProiz(arr, n) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но можете подсказать, в чем была ошибка?

Comment: В работе с указателями. Вы начинали, как я уже говорил, писать по нулевым адресам, в функциях вы тоже капитально запутались в указателях...